# Randomly generated polymer with certain spatial density

Tags: performance-tuning, graphics3d, simulation, rotation

For simplicity's sake, let the polymer's composing particle be integer 3-tuples (on 3D Cartesian grid), such that:

1. Polymer-ness -- for all particle there is an directly adjacent neighbor. i.e in directions of    {{0,0,1}, {0,0,-1}, {0,1,0}, {0,-1,0}, {1,0,0}, {-1,0,0}}
2. Of loose spacial density -- there's no more than $d_n$ particles in a radius $n$ sphere around each particle

The plot looks interesting. DLA-esque. In fact, if we let  $ d_n = <3^n> $,  it appears rather dimensionless i.e. factal looking

However my code was slow and it's a pain to generate a set larger than 400 particles (~7mins)

[image: 200 particles]

Moreover, how can I spin the plot independently around 2 spatial axis? (like that asteroid in Armageddon IYNWIM)

I tried ViewAngle and use 2 RotationTransform to rotate the vector. However, that's not how it seems to works.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
colorPalette = (#/3 + 0.2) & /@ {1, 2, 3};
radiusPlaette = {0.63, 0.53, 0.46};
adjLimit = {3, 9, 27, 81};
idx = Range[Length@adjLimit];
dir = {{1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 
 0, -1}};
pos = {{0, 0, 0}}; test = {};

adj[x_, d_] := Cases[pos, _?(EuclideanDistance[x, #] <= d &)];

Dynamic[Length[pos]]

(*Polymer, nice-looking spheres*)
Dynamic[
Graphics3D[{Hue[Take[colorPalette, {Mod[#2, 3] + 1}], 1, 0.1],
  Sphere[#1 - {0.5, 0.5, 0.5} - Mean[pos], 
   Take[radiusPlaette, {Mod[#2, 3] + 1}]]} & @@@ 
   MapThread[List, {pos, Range[Length@pos]}], Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> Automatic, SphericalRegion -> True ]]

(*Alternative layout
(*Colored Boxes*) 
Dynamic[Graphics3D[{Hue[1.*#2/3+0.15,0.7,1],Cuboid[#1-{0.5,0.5,0.5}-
Mean[pos]]}&@@@MapThread[List,{pos,Range[Length@pos]}],Axes->
False,Boxed->False,Lighting->{{"Ambient",White}}, SphericalRegion->True]]
*)

Timing[
 Do[
  out = Catch[While[True,
     stem = RandomChoice[pos];  
     rnd = stem + RandomChoice[dir];
     listadj1 = Length /@ (adj[rnd, #] & /@ idx);
         adj1 = And @@ MapThread[(#1 <= #2) &, {listadj1, adjLimit}];
     listadj2 = (Function[x, Max[Length /@ (adj[#, x] & /@ adj[rnd, x])]] /@ idx);
         adj2 = And @@ MapThread[(#1 <= #2) &, {listadj2, adjLimit}];

     If[! MemberQ[pos, rnd] && adj1 && adj2,(*Debug*)
      AppendTo[test, listadj2]; Throw[rnd]];
     ]];
  AppendTo[pos, out];
  , {399}]
 ]
(*Debug*)
Last@Sort[test]
Tally[Length /@ (adj[#, 2] & /@ pos)]
```

.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand your original code very well (particularly the definitions of `listadj1`  and `listadj2`), but here's my naive translation for your description, I only rewrote the simulation part:

```
densitytest = 
  With[{dis2 = idx^2, limit = adjLimit}, 
   Compile[{{pos, _Real, 2}}, 
    Times @@ 
     UnitStep@(limit + 1 - 
        Max /@ Transpose[Total /@ Map[UnitStep[dis2 - #] &,
            Map[Total, Outer[Plus, pos, -pos, 1]^2, {-2}], {-1}]])]];

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  Module[{pos2}, While[pos2 =!= pos,
    If[! MemberQ[pos, rnd = RandomChoice[pos] + RandomChoice[dir]], 
     pos2 = Flatten[{pos, {rnd}}, 1]; 
     If[1 == densitytest@pos2, pos = pos2]]]], {399}]]
```

[image]

I believe the code can be further optimized, but now I'd like to stop here and go to bed :)

---

**Update:**

I managed to further optimize the code, only about **40 seconds** are needed for 400 particles now:

```
densitytest = 
  With[{dis2 = idx^2, limit = adjLimit}, 
   Compile[{{pos, _Real, 2}}, 
    Times @@ UnitStep@(limit + 1 - Max /@ Total /@ UnitStep@Outer[Plus, dis2,
            -Total@Transpose[Outer[Plus, pos, -pos, 1]^2, {2, 3, 1}]])]];

AbsoluteTiming[Do[
  Module[{pos2, toselect = Complement[Flatten[Outer[Plus, pos, dir, 1], 1], pos]},
    While[pos2 =!= pos,
    pos2 = Flatten[{pos, {RandomChoice@toselect}}, 1]; 
    If[1 == densitytest@pos2, pos = pos2]]], {399}]]
```

Comment: 96 secs! That's virtuoso to me \^O^/

Comment: @秦紀維 And it's not the end, see my edit.